# How to observe local state with MobX react?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, mobx-react

Under useLocalStore in their [docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#uselocalstore-hook) they state, "Instead, if your store needs to refer to props (or useState based local state), the useLocalStore should be combined with the useAsObservableSource hook, see below."

I just want to make my useState observable in the useLocalStore but cant figure it out.

Here is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-react-observable-local-state-mpi8q?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I changed the:

```
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    active: observableActive.active
    
  }));
```

to

```
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    get active(){
      return observableActive.active
    } 
  }));
```